# Replacing a covering in a site with a single arrow

Tags: category-theory

When we work in a site with a pretopology, what is the phenomenon called that one can replace a covering $\lbrace A_i\to B\rbrace$ with a single covering $V\to B$ (is $V$ always the pullback $A_{i_1}\times_B A_{i_2}\cdots$?) and when can one do this?

Is all the information one needs for the covering encompassed in that one arrow? Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is okay as long as the sheaves you're looking at take disjoint unions to products. In this case you can always replace your $A_i\rightarrow B$'s with $\sqcup_i A_i\rightarrow B$.

Comment: The answer is essentially contained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1224535/5191)